# Greasemonkey, Chrome and unsafeWindow.foo()

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, greasemonkey, google-chrome-extension

I have the following anchor tag, which contains dynamically-generated arguments `arg1,...,arg5` to the JavaScript function `foo()`, which runs on the web site-side. There are several of these anchor tags throughout the page in question, with unique `id` values and `argN` values:

```
<a href="#" id="foo1234567890" onclick="javascript:foo(arg1,arg2,arg3,arg4,arg5);return false;" target="_self" title="foobarbaz"> blah </a>
```

I would like to programmatically fire the `foo()` function by looping through all hits for this element, searching for the arguments, and passing those arguments to Greasemonkey's `unsafeWindow.function(args)` call.

Here is the Greasemonkey script I have written so far:

```
function removeAllProperties() {
    var xpath = "//A[@title='foobarbaz']";
    var actionNodes = document.evaluate(
                                    xpath,
                                    document,
                                    null,
                                    XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE,
                                    null
                                    );
    var total = actionNodes.snapshotLength;

    for (var i=0; i < total; i++) {
        var candidate = actionNodes.snapshotItem(i);
        //alert(candidate.nodeName);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
        if (candidate.nodeName === "A") {
            var onclick_value = candidate.getAttribute('onclick');
            var needle = /javascript:foo\((.*)\);return false\;/;
            onclick_value.match(needle);
            //alert(onclick_value);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
            //alert(RegExp.$1);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
            var script_args = RegExp.$1;
            if (confirm(script_args)) { 
                unsafeWindow.foo(script_args); 
            }
        }
    }
}

removeAllProperties();
```

When I install this script and run it, I get the alert with the arguments `arg1,...,arg5`. If I click OK, I get the following error in Google Chrome 5.0.375.125 for OS X:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object DOMWindow] has no method 'foo'
```

The web page in question definitely has `foo()` — if I click on `blah` then the `onclick` event triggers `foo()`. I just can't get it working through this Greasemonkey script.

Am I using `unsafeWindow.function(args)` incorrectly, or does Google Chrome not support this method of triggering remote JavaScript functions?

Is there a different way I should use this function, or should I use another method entirely?

Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Chrome, you're not allowed to access variables/functions defined by the content page from the userscript context (see [here](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html)).

Instead of calling `unsafeWindow.foo`, you could just call `candidate.onclick()` in your loop.

If that isn't what you want, you either have to inject the function call into the DOM using something like

```
var s = document.createElement("script");
s.innerHTML = "foo("+ script_args + ")";
document.body.appendChild(s);
```

or assign a JS-uri to `location`:

```
location.assign("javascript:foo(" + script_args +");void 0");
```